# Elastic Search _search vs. _count syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

It would appear that _search and _count take different formats for queries. For example, this is my `_search` query:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: { match: { Name: "bob" } },
      filter: { term: { GroupIds: 3 } }
    }
  }
}
```

But in order for `_count` to comprehend it I need to remove the outer `query`:

```
{
  filtered: {
    query: { match: { Name: "bob" } },
    filter: { term: { GroupIds: 3 } }
  }
}
```

That one will not work with `_search`. Just to further confuse me more, `_search` will accept it if both `query` **and** `filtered` are removed:

```
{
  query: { match: { Name: "bob" } },
  filter: { term: { GroupIds: 3 } }
}
```

So what is the actual rule for the Query DSL when using `_search` vs. `_count`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search is one of the most complex operations in elasticsearch and as a result it accepts several different parameters on the top level including `query`, `filter`, `facets`, `size` and so on.

The `query` parameter should contain a query as defined by Query DSL. It can be any query including `match_all` or `filtered`. For example, here is how search request would look like that accepts all records and returns top 20.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 20
}
```

The `filter` parameter in the search request can accept a filter (again as defined in Query DSL). This filter has special function in the search - it doesn't affect any facets in the request. So, typically it makes sense to use the `filter` parameter only with faceted search when you want to filter search results but you don't want to affect facets. In all other cases, the `filtered` query would typically produces faster results.

Speaking of which, the `filtered` query is a query, so it can be used in the `query` parameter of the search request. It's also a compound query. It accepts another query in its `query` parameter and a filter in its `filter` parameter and produces a compound query that returns only documents that satisfy both the query and the filter that it consists of. In other words, the `filter` parameter in the `filtered` query affects both search results and facets, while the `filter` parameter in the `search` query affects only search result and doesn't affect facets.

And finally the `count` request. The `count` requests is much simpler than the `search` request. It doesn't work with facets and size parameter wouldn't really make much sense since we always request complete count. So, all the `count` request expects is one query on the top level. For example, in order to count all documents the `count` request would contain something like this:

```
{
    "match_all": {}
}
```

Comment: Great explanation Igor, as usual!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: This answer is relevant for earlier versions of ES.  In v1.3.4 Count API now requires us to wrap in an outer query.