# ElasticSearch _count and _search apply same query

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm trying get count of total results for paginator, but the problem is that _filter and _count have different arguments, for example:

**_search:**

```
 'from' => $offset,
 'size' => $limit,
 'query' => [
   'match_phrase' => $q,
 ]
```

**_count:**

```
'index' => $index,
'type' => $type,
'q' => $q,
```

I need apply **match_phrase** also inside _count, because when will keep there just **q** then count/number will don't be correct...but does _count accept **match_phrase**?

It's _count right way or must use different way? I was searching long hours, but found just this [Elastic Search _search vs. _count syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492055/elastic-search-search-vs-count-syntax) but it's saying nothing for me..

Comment: Response of `_search` gives the total count as well. Why there is the requirement to use `_count` api?

Comment: i dont want get all results (i want only one number) and want know total count before _search..

Comment: The `_count` [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) works the same as the `_search` API, where the query being sent in the body must be nested in a `query` key. You could also do some [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) with the `_search` API, removing the contents of `_source` in the response and reading total count with the `hits` field.